# EXCEL MACRO - perform vlookup only on blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, filter, vlookup

I have a simple table with 2 columns - the first column has the numbers 1 to 10, and the second column SHOULD have the spelled-out versions of the numbers (i.e. One, Two, Three, ..., Ten).

I would like to write a macro that performs a vlookup on the table to automatically fill in the second column using the values from the first column as the vlookup reference, but ONLY on the cells that aren't already filled in (i.e. only on blank cells).

I have the following code which executes when I click the macro-enabled button:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()

    Range("B3").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=""   
    Range("C3:C12").Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("B3:B12"),     
    Sheet2.Range("B2:C11"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

The first line filters the list so that only blanks show up.
The second line should apply the `vlookup` only to the cells that are filtered. But, when I leave some of the cells blank, and execute the macro, it incorrectly performs the `vlookup`. For example, if I delete the data for row 4 and row 7 (i.e. delete "Four" and "Seven"), and perform the `vlookup`, it filters the list properly, but instead of pulling "Four" and "Seven" from the `vlookup` table, it pulls up "One" and "One".

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The value will be pulled for the first cell, not the individual ones.

Try this instead, first getting the formula to calculate the right value for each cell, then pasting that cell's value.

```
dim rgLoop as range

Range("B3").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=""   

Range("C3:C12").specialcells(xlcelltypevisible).formular1c1="=VLookup(RC2, Sheet2!B2:C11, 2, False)"

for each rgLoop in Range("C3:C12").specialcells(xlcelltypevisible)
    rgLoop.value=rgLoop.value
next rgLoop
```

Comment: True that. I have deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with this code? It seems a bit of an odd use case.

Anyway - I would not bother with a macro, I would just add a column with something like:

> =if([CellWithWordIn]<>"",[CellWithWordIn], Vlookup Formula)

this would minimize the vlookup calls, the extra if functions should not be a problem.